# What does compareTo method return in java

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

I have a code snippet, that finds median in an array and then sort that array depends on proximity to the median(from least to greatest), but i can't understand how that stuff works

```
 public static Integer[] sort(Integer[] array)
    {
        Arrays.sort(array);
        final double median;
        if (array.length % 2 == 0)
            median = ((double)array[array.length/2-1]+ (double)array[array.length/2])/2;
        else
            median =  array [array.length/2];

        Comparator<Integer> compareToMedian= new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
            {
                double value = Math.abs(o1 - median) - Math.abs(o2 - median);
                if (value == 0)
                    value = o1 - o2;
                return (int)value;
            }
        };

        Arrays.sort(array, compareToMedian);
        return array;
    }
```

What i really find confusing is what exactly value means in this particular case. Does it just sort result from least to greatest? Like i have `result` equals to -5 in one case, -2 in another and 3 and eventually it becomes -5, -2, 3? And sorts the array?

Comment: Well did you read the documentation for `Comparator.compare`? What have you tried in terms of debugging this code? Your "Like i have" sentence doesn't makes much sense to me at the moment, particularly as `result` doesn't occur anywhere in the code...

Comment: :(:(:(:(:(:(:(:(

Comment: Are you asking what the return value of [`compare`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) means, or are you asking how the math `Math.abs(o1 - median) - Math.abs(o2 - median)` works? See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html.

Comment: I'm asking what is the sorting based on. On return value or what? And if so, how it works?

Comment: I think you mean `compare`, not `compareTo`. `Comparator` has `compare`, which is what you have in your code. `Comparable` has `compareTo`.

Comment: Yes, i meant compare

Comment: So did you read the documentation as suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### compareTo() return an int to show which value is greater

0 if both equal

+ve if first value is greater

-ve if second value is greater

---

compareTo(5,5) returns 0

compareTo(6,5) returns anything positive

compareTo(5,6) returns anything negative

```
//    going line by line for explanation

    public static Integer[] sort(Integer[] array)
    {
        Arrays.sort(array);//first of all sort the numbers in increasing order
        final double median;
        /*
        now in sorted numbers median is the
        --- average of middle two values for even count of numbers; like for 10 numbers median is (4th item +5th item )/2
        --- middle value if there are odd count of numbers like for 11 items the median is the 6th item
         */
        if (array.length % 2 == 0)
            median = ((double)array[array.length/2-1]+ (double)array[array.length/2])/2;
        else
            median =  array [array.length/2];
        //now we have the median



//        here we have a Comparator for comparing any value during with the median value
        Comparator<Integer> compareToMedian= new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
            {
//                first we check the distance of two numbers from the median; that is the difference from the median
                double value = Math.abs(o1 - median) - Math.abs(o2 - median);
                if (value == 0)//if the difference is same then we compare the numbers
                    value = o1 - o2;
                return (int)value;//otherwise we return the difference
            }
        };

        Arrays.sort(array, compareToMedian);//sort the numbers with respect to median
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped a little, but i still wondering how return value affects on array order.  Does it just check every value in array with value of return using bubble sort or what?

Comment: you compare two items in the array until the end using the rule as given by the Compartor(in the compareTo method). Further Arrays.sort is not bubble sort but much faster sort technique.

Comment: @javafan thanks, nice website by the way Quadgen. Hope i made the code clear.